# Time shift between tracked camera motion and original movie

Tags: rendering, tracking

I tracked a sample movie clip and put a cube in the center. It animated quite well, and I was even able to see the video by playing (Render > Play) a set of PNG files.

I then changed options to export to H.264 and the result was quite bad - it looks like I somehow created a lag between the camera tracking and the video. It seems object on frame X is shown as if the camera is on frame X + 1, so the object moves just slightly ahead of the video.

What did I break?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the video playing back smoothly? or is there a slowdown giving a wave like effect as the frame gets updated, giving the appearance of the object moving at a different time to other parts of the video?

Comment: The video playback is fine. I even switched back to a list of PNGs, and this playbacks fine as well, but with the camera position matched to the wrong frame.

Comment: If you clearly get two different rendered results when saving to png or h264 then I would consider reporting a bug. Are you using 2.68, tried 2.69rc2, 2.67? Bugs can be reported through [projects.blender.org](https://projects.blender.org)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was with the video settings not matching the render settings. The video was recorded with a cellphone camera, and came out as 24.856 frames per second. Strange indeed.
If I repeat the process on a list of PNGs, or a video shot with a decent camera that produces a decent frame rate, this works fine.

Thanks for all the helpful comments.